# How can I create a mixed, "Master-Detail and Tabbar" application in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to create a Master-Detail iPad application with a list of saved files in the Master view, and the main interface in the detail view. There will be many different views in the detail and master, however, and I would like to be able to use a tab bar so users can quickly move between different aspects of the app. How would I go about it.

Ideally I would like to create master-detail template and build on top of that.

[image]

Comment: Well what can one say? YES. Find How.

Answer (score 3):

In a Master-Detail template application:

1. Select the storyboard file to open it in the storyboard editor.
2. Select the default Navigation Controller.
3. From Xcode's menu bar, select Editor -> Embed In -> Tab Bar Controller.

To add another tab:

1. Find the view controller you want to display in the tab in the library.
2. Drag the view controller from the library and place it on the canvas.
3. Control drag from the Tab Bar Controller to the newly placed view controller.
4. In the small popup menu, select 'view controllers' under the Relationship Segue section.

NOTE: The tabs at the bottom of the Tab Bar Controller will appear in the same order in which you connected them in Storyboard. It appears that there is no way to change the order of the tabs in the latest version of Xcode except by deleting the relationship segues you created and recreating them in the desired order.

Comment: In #2 you mention selecting the default Navigation Controller... I'm not sure how to determine which that is. There doesn't appear to be a nav controller at a level higher than the 'Split View Controller' so I'm not sure this approach will work... ??

Comment: Good point. I did test my own answer but I used the iPhone template and the original question was for an iPad app.

Comment: there is an easier way you can reorder the tabs by highlighting the tab bar controller that is set as the initial view controller, select a tab item and drag to desired location.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to create a tab bar at the bottom as in pictures below?

Yes.

Its a fairly straightforward tab bar with 6 Table View Controllers (Loaded with the same Data) as masters and a detail controller with one of your option screens.

Your detail Controllers will have a table view inside a view controller with its rows acting to programmatically return to the Master View and select the desired segue to display the new view controller.

Itunes U course CP193P at Stanford by Paul Hegarty is a great help in familiarizing yourself with the code and methodology.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to created tabs and no each tab has different data.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do so, 

What i can suggest you

- Alloc and Initialize  UITabbarcontroller and Add its view to The Master Or Detail View Controller  according to your preferrence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

```
tabBarcontroller
|
|__SplitVC
|
|_anotherVC
```

In the place of first viewcontroller in tab bar place the splitviewcontroller

Comment: But in master-detail app, tabBarController cannot be root controller? When I do this application crashes

Comment: Your desing ask for this way.Right?It is the first tab showing splitvc

Answer (score 0):

Even though if your other tabs contain Master-Detail-Views as well, you should make your UITabBarController the first item in your view hierarchy. Each tab should then link to its own UISplitViewController which has a master and a detail view to the actual ViewControllers which make up your UI.

If you want't to display similar data in the same way in different tabs, you can create a shared datasource/delegate instead of implementing the datasource and delegate in each ViewController. However, if you are already displaying the same data in the same way, maybe a different tab is not what you need. Maybe then it is better to have a filter or so, like you already have on you master (the segmented control)